# pip install pkg gives Permission denied: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

Funny one today after reinstalling Python 2 on homebrew using `brew reinstall python`.

**Exception**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3’
```

**Relevant stuff**

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ echo $PYTHONPATH
$
```

Pretty sure this is using the OS X system Python but can't work out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - homebrew wants me to use `pip2` not `pip` after reinstall.

I probably should have read the docs, but anyway thats not the main issue...

The top line of the file `/usr/local/bin/pip` is now
`#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`

This is the problem. Changing this line to either:

A. `#!/usr/local/bin/python` or

B. `` #!`brew --prefix`/bin/python ``

fixes the problem.

Note: I can't 100% blame this on homebrew. Note sure what happened here but the issue is fixed for me.

Also I could have run `sudo pip ...` but that would have messed with the macOS system `site-packages` directory which is generally considered not a great idea.